# import large records into Absolute Database

Tags: database, absolute

i have 4.000.000 records and above.
i want import into Absolute Database from access.
what's the best way and speedly method?

Answer (score 1):

Use the import/export demo in Absolute demo's

Answer (score 0):

Use ABC Amber Absolute Converter. Very easy to use and free too ... here is the link : http://www.softpedia.com/progDownload/ABC-Amber-Absolute-Converter-Download-107364.html